# "Uniformly choosing" from $\mathbb Q\cap(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Take the set of rational numbers $Q=\mathbb Q\cap(a,b)$.

**Step 1:** Start with an arbitrary sequence $Q_0=\left\{q_1, q_2,\ldots\right\}=Q$ where each rational number appears exactly once.
**Step 2:** Choose a uniform random number $u$ in $[0,1].$
**Step 3:** Map $u$ to $f_u$ using a bijection $f:[0,1]\hookrightarrow \Pi_{\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ where $\Pi_{\mathbb{N}}$ is the set of permutations on $\mathbb N.$
**Step 4:** Apply the permutation $f_u$ to the sequence in step 1: 
$$f_u(Q_0)=\left\{q_{_{f_u(1)}},q_{_{f_u(2)}},\ldots\right\}.$$

The result should be a randomly shuffled list of rationals.

**Question:** is each shuffling of $Q$ "equally likely"? (Each has probability zero of course.) The goal is that each random number is in a sense uniformly distributed in $Q$. Of course such a uniform distribution does not exist.

I'm thinking along the lines of mapping infinite sequences of fair coin flips to binary decimal representations.

If the above is all correct (or nearly so), then have we found a process for "uniformly choosing" from the space of all listings of $Q$ in such a way that $$x_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n q_{_{f_u(k)}}\overset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac{a+b}{2}?$$

If each $q_n$ in the list $\left\{q_1,q_2,\ldots\right\}$ is equally likely to be anywhere in $(a,b),$ then the averages should tend to the middle of the interval. I may end up being way in over my head though. It should be an easier construction if we truncated the list of rationals to be finite in size, but maybe there are some technical convergence issues with that approach.

Comment: The sets $\{u\in[0,1]\mid f_u(k)=n\}$ are most probably non measurable, for each $(k,n)$.

Comment: Ah. So the whole question is moot! I'll have to think about that.

Comment: Is the point is that a measurable bijection $f$ does not exist in this case?